# HTTP Post with JSON

Tags: c#, json, post

I can't seem to get the hang of my HTTP POST methods. I have just learned how to do GET methods to retrieve webpages but now i'm trying to fill in information on the webpage and can't seem to get it working. The source code that comes back is always an invalid page (full of broken images/not the right information)

```
public static void jsonPOST(string url)
{
            url = "http://treasurer.maricopa.gov/Parcel/TaxReceipt.aspx/GetTaxReceipt";
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate");
            httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5");
            httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW65; Trident/7.0; MAM5; rv:11.0) like Gecko";
            httpWebRequest.Referer = "http://treasurer.maricopa.gov/Parcel/TaxReceipt.aspx";


            string postData = "{\"startDate\":\"1/1/2013\",\"parcelNumber\":\"17609419\"}";
            byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
            httpWebRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            System.IO.Stream os = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //Push it out there
            os.Close();

            System.Net.WebResponse resp = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            if (resp == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("null");
            }
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            string source = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
}
```

EDIT: I updated the code to reflect my new problem. The problem i have now is that the source code is not what is coming back to me. I am getting just the raw JSON information in the `source`. Which i can use to deserialize the information i need to obtain, but i'm curious why the actual source code isn't coming back to me

Comment: Is this ASP.NET MVC or WebForms?

Comment: This is a console app that i'm trying to have just scrape for some information for our companies database

Answer (score 0):

The source code that comes back is always an invalid page (full of broken images/not the right information)

It sounds like you just get the Source code without thinking of relative paths. As long as there are relative paths on the site it will not show correctly at your copy. You have to replace all the relative paths before it is useful.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm

Remember crossdomain ajax can be a problem in that situation.